# [FCM][iOS] Messaging.messaging().token gives a request timed out for China

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Environment:**

Firebase SDK version: 7.0.0

**Problem:**

We have used following code snippet (as given in the doc) to get the FCM Token,

```
Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
  } else if let token = token {
    print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
  }
}
```

And this works as expected in US,SL, etc but it gives the following error for all the iOS devices in China,

```
Error fetching FCM registration token: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <22F1AB3C ...>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <22F1AB3C ...>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
```

Has anyone else noticed this behaviour?